# Is reorganizing a partition effectively the same as copying data from one table to another?

Tags: mysql, partitioning

If I have a maxvalue partition as such:

`PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE`

and then reorganize the partition so that it has two partitions - one for older data and one for current data:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable REORGANIZE PARTITION p0 INTO (
    PARTITION p20220401 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2022-04-01')),
    PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE 
)
```

Should I expect the process of reorganizing the partition to require similar server resources (i/o, cpu, memory) as though the same amount of data were being copied to new tables?

Is there a good way to benchmark this where I could possibly predict what I might expect in production?

Thank you in advance for any insight...

Answer (score 0):

[To the title question] Yes.

Use sane partition naming.

- `p0` sounds like the partition with the smallest dates.  Instead call it `future`.
- `p20220401` should contain row *starting* with, not *ending* before April 1.

But if the "future" partition is still empty, the reorg will be very fast.

That is, reorg the empty partition called `future` into `p_2022_07` (next month) and `future` just *before* July 1.  Then just before 8/1, p_2022_07 will be full and it is time to create p_2022_08.

This will leave a trail of monthly partitions.  It is [usually] not practical to worry about how many there are.

I discuss that issue (and others) in [*Partition*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint)

Note that `SELECTs` are quite happy to search one or many or even all partitions.  "Partition pruning" will happen if the `WHERE` clause includes a test on the column being used as the "partition key".

Your description was not clear on why you think partitioning will help.

Show us the main `SELECTs` so I can help in designing the `PRIMARY KEY` and any secondary `INDEXes`.  The tips are different than for non-partitioned tables.

**Sample**

Initially create the table with a strange `PRIMARY KEY`; it will never need to be changed or rebuilt:

```
CREATE TABLE (
    id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    dt ... DATETIME,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY(id, dt),
    ...
    PARTITION BY RANGE (TO_DAYS(dt)) ...
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

The weekly (or however often) `DROP PARTITION` will throw away a bunch of ids; no problem.

The weekly `REORGANIZE PARTITION` will build a new partition which will receive ids with higher values and dates that are newer.

(Since you don't have that PK, there is a big effort to ALTER; this would require a one-time downtime.  Using `pt-online-schema-change` might be a way to avoid the downtime.)

Comment: We have an app with a rolling ~6months of accessible data. Data prior is not accessible to users & can effectively be deleted. We were looking to partition on a "created date" column. We only need 1 partition of active data & 1 partition of inactive data which we could then drop after moving from active. One partition per month created in advance also makes sense. At any one time we would have ~6 partitions. The downside is we won't be able to update the application to specify which partition to query so it will always have to scan every partition. Better to have 1 big partition or 6 smaller?

Comment: "which partition to query" -- Just query the table; don't worry about which partition(s) are needed.

Comment: 1 big / 6 small.  Based on what you have said, I would do weekly partitions (about 28 partitions).  See the discussion in my link.

Comment: Thank you for your insightful comments - After posting the initial question I started to seriously consider that we could just run a job daily to delete a day's worth of data. This wouldn't incur the overhead of having to drop and recreate the primary key for example. One of our tables is already at 100 M rows which means the prerequisite schema changes will be very painful to deploy.  Would you view deleting rows from the table (in off hours, of course) as a viable alternative to partitioning?

Comment: @user19339351 - `DELETE` is much slower than `DROP PARTITION`.  The PK never needs to be dropped and recreated.

Comment: The primary key on the table currently does not include the created_date column which is what we want to partition on. The documentation states that since the primary key is a unique key it needs to include the columns used for partitioning. This would require recreating the pk as a prerequisite to adding the partitions. If that is not the case it would be a huge relief. So far though, I haven't been able to figure out any other way. If you have additional links or pointers I would be grateful...

Comment: @user19339351 - Sorry, no 'huge relief'.  I added to my Answer.

Comment: One last question - what is the benefit of a weekly partition over a monthly partition? Thank you so much!

Comment: @user19339351 not a lot of difference.  A 3-week difference in the max size before shrinking.  DROP PARTITION takes 4 times as long (but still probably sub-second).